# Does the company with the website zug-erstattung.de still exist?

Tags: trains, germany, deutsche-bahn

There used to be a company with the website

Zug-Erstattung.de .

It was useful for claiming penalty payments from Deutsche Bahn for delayed or cancelled trains. Does it still exist?

Answer (score 2):

I see no indication that the site still exists. This is probably because there is no reason to use such a service.

To get your money back, you can either use the online form if you have a bahn.de account and booked your ticket there, a paper form (available [here](https://www.bahn.de/wmedia/view/mdb/media/intern/fahrgastrechteformular-englisch.pdf), or sometimes handed out in a delayed train), or any service center at a station.

There is no wiggling around like with some airlines. If you have a valid claim, you'll get your money.

Comment: The bureaucracy with this company was less than with Deutsche Bahn.

Comment: @MartinPeters What bureaucracy? If you look at the form I linked, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: @helm It is not complicated to claim the refund or compensation, but to actually get it. The last time I did so (partial refund of a ticket they sold to a service they eventually didn't operate), they refused the claim since according to their T&Cs, I do not have the right to a refund in this case and 9 months later after threateting with legal actions, they still only offered me a coupon for future travel instead of a real refund.